# is this a good presentation of tawheed proofs?

Tags: theology

since any necassery existance or God is absolute and one,he is absolutely one.
a composite one would be a generic and abstract 'one',and abstractions do not have concrete and actual existance,so any actual being must be absolutely one.

and that multiplicity in any essence must be by nature contigent(if someone knows why then add it and do give your wisdom)and a accidental property.

and 'necasseriness'and 'being'are by definition ontologically absolutely one(if anyone can answer why that would help me).
IDK,I made up this argument after making dua that sayyiduna muhammed said would always be answered for farasa in knowing absolute yaqeen of tawheed(I come from a trinitarian backround).

any help or corrections are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

These proofs aren't really proofs. No one can prove if there are no other Gods with Allah, but one can say if it is likely that there are none or if it is unlikely, but because it's very out of the reach of our hearts and brains, we really can't say except believe in Allah, the Truthful. I would say the best argument, that made me believe that Allah is really Alone, is that Allah, God is *transcendant*.

Allah isn't like us, He isn't like His creatures, that multiply, because if they didn't, they would die (no one is immortal). Does Allah fear death ? Does Allah need then to have similar beings ?

Allah's nature is to be Alone. His nature is fundamentally different from the nature of His creation. His creation is never one (you never see anything *truly* unique in the universe), so Allah is fundamentally Alone.

This obviously only works if the verse 11 of Surah As-Shura is believed :

> "Nothing resembles Him (Allah) in any way"